# Change VIM gui tab width

Tags: tabs, vim

In GVim can one change the width of the GUI's tabs (i.e. the tab labels at the top that show `guitablabel`)?

In particular, the tab labels aren't wide for a `guitablabel=%f` or anything of that length.

Thanks

Comment: @Kemp - yep, it was - thanks for it! Glad you got the bounty. :)

Comment: Does anybody know how to do this without a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1507): it seems to offer a wide variety of options for configuring your tabs, including variables that handle minimum and maximum width, using the full path of a file, etc.